# Lucene and Nickname matching

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a series of docs containing a nickname ( even with spaces ) and an ID.

The nickname can be like ["example","nick n4me", "nosp4ces","A fancy guy"].

I have to find a query that allow me to find profiles by a perfect matching, a fuzzy, or event with partial character.

So if a write down "nick" or "nick name" or "nick name", the document "nickname" has always to come out.

I tried with something like:

```
nickname:(%1%^4 %1%~^3 %1%*^1)
```

where "%1%" is what I'm searching, but it doesn't work, especially for spaces or numbers nicknames. For example if i try to search "nick n" the query would be:

```
nickname:(nick n^4 nick n~^3 nick n*^1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Boosting with `^` will only affect the scoring and not the matching, i.e. if your query does not match at all, boosting the terms or not won't make any difference.

In your specific example, the query won't match because:

1) `nick n` won't match because that would require that either the token `nick` or `n` have been tokenized;

2) EDIT: I found out that fuzzy queries work only on single terms, if you use the standard query parser. In your case, you should probably rewrite `nick n~` using [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html), so you can do a fuzzy query on the whole `PhraseQuery`. Also, you can specify a threshold for your fuzzy query (technically, you are specifying a minimum Levenshtein distance). Obviously you have to adjust the threshold, and that usually requires some trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

An easier tactic is to load all nicknames into one field -- in your example you would have 4 values for your nickname field. If you want embedded spaces in your nicknames, you will need to use a simpler analyzer than StandardAnalyzer or use phrase searches.